# Access Denied Opening DocX File

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, openxml-sdk

I have a class, and in the same folder I have a .docx file.

The below code is producing a yellow screen of death, claiming access is denied on the document (but in the System32 folder). I have added ASPNET and Network Service as users with modify permissions on the document, in the project's folder (NOT system32).

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("FileName.docx", true)) {}
```

I'm sure this is something simple and common, but I'm not turning up anything on Google.

Running IIs 7 and .Net 4.

Cheers

Comment: Which version of .NET and IIS are you using?

Comment: Don't forget read permissions and write permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file had to have the Build Action set to "Content" in order for it to actually copy to the correct place. In addition to that, I also switched from "filename.docx" to Server.MapPath("filename.docx").

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for the file in the current directory, which will be the `System32` folder.  If you want it to look somewhere else, you can specify the path rather than just `FileName.docx` as the filename.